# How to convert an integer to char in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to get the ASCII character of an integer in java, but it is giving me an empty char when I try to typecast it. I am doing:

```
int slowest = keyTimes.get(keyIndex).first;
```

where keyTimes is a List of PairInts and PairInt has 2 integers, first and second. I am then doing

```
char ch = (char) slowest;
```

but this does not give me the ASCII character, and prints blank.

Comment: It would help if you could paste a [mre] into the question as text. For debugging, I would suggest printing the integers to the consol.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a=65;  
char c=(char)a;
System.out.println(a);
```

This will give "A" as output. Also give black output if there is no ASCII character of given number. So please check the integer that you are providing.

Answer (score 0):

If printing `ch` results in empty space, then `slowest` value would be 32 as ASCII value of space is 32.
You can check the ASCII to character mapping at [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)